# How to allow users to create and delete file(s) / folder(s), but not modify them?

Tags: permissions, files, directory, restricted-access, acl

I have created a group name "app-data" and a folder /db-data/archived-data/

I want members of app-data to have all rights on /db-data/ folder but I want the same group users have only create and delete access on /db-data/archived-data/ folder (users should not be able to modify any files or directories in it. but they should be able to create or delete any files or folders they want.

How can we do it. I think this is possible through ACL but please feel free to let me know how can we achive this? using any method I am fine but I want this configuration.

please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible. First, change `/db-data`'s group to `app-data`:

```
sudo chgrp -R app-data /db-data
```

Now set up the permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /db-data
sudo chmod -R g-w /db-data/archived-data/*
sudo find /db-data/archived-data -type d -exec 'chmod' 'g+rwx' '{}' ';'
```

- `sudo chmod -R g+rwx /db-data` gives `app-data` full permissions to `/db-data` and everything inside it
- `sudo chmod -R g-w /db-data/archived-data/*` removes `app-data`'s write permissions for everything inside `/db-data/archived-data`
- Finally, `sudo find /db-data/archived-data -type d -exec 'chmod' 'g+rwx' '{}' ';'` restores `app-data`'s write permissions for every **directory** in `/db-data/archived-data` (but **not** the files inside those directories), which is necessary to let `app-data` create and delete any files or directories inside `/db-data/archived-data`.

Now anyone in `app-data` will be able to read, execute, create, and delete files or directories in `/db-data/archived-data` (including sub-directories deeper than 1 level; i.e. `app-data` will be able to create and delete files in `/db-data/archived-data/a/b/`). If you don't want `app-data` to have read and/or execute permissions either, change the `g-w` in `sudo chmod -R g-w /db-data/archived-data/*` to `g-rw` for no read permissions, `g-wx` for no execute permissions, or `g-rwx` for no permissions at all (if you do this after running the `find` command, you will have to re-run it).

Finally, note that **if a user in** `app-data` **creates a file or directory, he/she will be able to modify the file/directory that he/she created** (but existing files will still be unmodifiable).

Comment: Users should not be able to create files or folder in /db-data folder. will the above thing change that?

Comment: @Rishee Ah, I thought you meant you wanted `app-data` to have full rights (including creation and deletion) to everything in `/db-data` except for  `/db-data/archived-data`. I will edit my answer shortly with a solution for this.

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you can edit the answer to fit the requirements.